# Excel:- Difference b/w pivot value col in multileveled table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

My Raw table looks like this.

[image]

When I create a Pivot it looks like the below screenshot. I have filtered the type column and not actual and others. Now i want to subtract these two columns and create just one more additional column. Maybe some column will show 0 here as I have created dummy data, Sorry for that

Can somebody please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a `calculated field/column`

This is a very easy and simple guide to do so here: [How to create a Calculated Field in Pivot Table](https://trumpexcel.com/excel-pivot-table-calculated-field/)

Because your data set is not complete, I am unable to replicate and provide results.

Please mark answer as `'accepted'` if you have found this response meets your requirements.